# Issue with combining large array of numbers into one single number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert an array of numbers into one single number, for example

```
[1,2,3] to 123.
```

However, my code can't handle big arrays since it can’t return exact number. Such as

```
[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3] returns 6145390195186705000
```

Is there any way that I could properly convert into a single number.I would really appreciate any help.

```
var integer = 0;
var digits = [1,2,3,4]
//combine array of digits into int
digits.forEach((num,index,self) => {
    integer += num * Math.pow(10,self.length-index-1)
});
```

Comment: Use BigInt libraries or save them as string and manipulate them as number

Comment: Check out [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin). You number is higher than max safe integer in js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 3):

The biggest integer value javacript can hold is **+/- 9007199254740991**. Note that the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is `2^31-1`, or 2147483647.

In my opinion, you can choose one of the following:

- store the numbers as strings and manipulate them as numbers; you might have to implement special functions to add/subtract/multiply/divide them (these are classic algorithmic problems)
- use the [BigInt](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint); BigInts are a new numeric primitive in JavaScript that can represent integers with arbitrary precision. With BigInts, you can safely store and operate on large integers even beyond the safe integer limit. Unfortunately, they work only with Chrome right now. If you want to work with other browsers, you might check [this](https://silentmatt.com/biginteger/) or even [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) if you work with angularjs or nodejs.

Try the following code in the Chrome's console:

```
let x = BigInt([6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3].join(''));
console.log(x);
```

This will print `6145390195186705543n`. The `n` suffix marks that it is a big integer.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am doing a programming exercise called "Add one" and the tests environment does not allow me to use BigInt.

Comment: @user545871 You are welcome! You may mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript Array join() Method and parse it into integer.
Example:
parseInt([6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5].join(''))
results:
6145390195186705

Edited: Use BigInt instead of parseInt , but it works only on chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

The largest number possible in Javascript is 
**+/- 9007199254740991**

Use `BigInt`. Join all numbers as a `string` and pass it in `BigInt` global function to convert it into `int`

```
var integer = 0;
var digits = [1,2,3,4]
//combine array of digits into int
digits.forEach((num,index,self) => {
    integer += num;
});
integer= BigInt(integer);
```

**Note :** Works only on Chrome as of now. You can use othee libraries like **BigInteger.js** or **MathJS**