# Converting an array of digits into a number for large numbers ignores some digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I am converting array digits into a number e.g. [1,2,4] = 124.

This code is working for smaller values but when I checked for big values like `[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]`, I was not able to add the last 543 to my sum.

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    let tsum = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        let k =Math.pow(10, (digits.length - (i + 1)));
        tsum = arr[i]* k;
        console.log(tsum);
        sum = sum + tsum;
        console.log(sum);
    }
    console.log(sum);
    sum= sum + 1;
    let cnt=0;
    while (sum!=0) {
        digits.unshift(Math.floor(sum%10));
        sum = Math.floor(sum/10); 
        cnt++;
    }
    digits.length = cnt;
    return digits;
};
let arr = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3];
console.log(plusOne(arr));
```

Comment: These are large numbers, for this you might need to use `BigInt`. Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers

Answer (score 0):

First, join the digits and make a string:

```
const joined =[6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3].join('')
// output: "6145390195186705543"
```

Second, convert the string to a BigInt:

```
const number = BigInt(joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method for adding a one to a an array of digits won’t work for large numbers. JavaScript stores all numbers as a floating point, so as Darshna Rehka and pesehr suggested, you should use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for this. See [Issue with combining large array of numbers into one single number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54019143/8289918)
for more information.

Although this doesn’t directly answer your question, here’s a different implementation of `plusOne` that should work for larger numbers:

```js
const plusOne = digits => {
    // Base case: treat empty arrays as 0 so return [1]
    // This part is important for the recursion below
    if (!digits.length) return [1];
    const init = digits.slice(0, -1);
    const last = digits[digits.length - 1];
    return last === 9
        // 9 + 1 = 10, carry the 1 (add 1 to the rest of the digits)
        // If there are no more digits to the left of the 9 (init.length === 0),
        // plusOne(init) will just return [1] (base case)
        ? [...plusOne(init), 0]
        // Simply add 1 to the last digit and keep the rest
        : [...init, last + 1];
};
const arr = [6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 9, 5, 1, 8, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 4, 3];
console.log(plusOne(arr).join(''));
console.log(plusOne([1, 8, 9]).join(''));
console.log(plusOne([9, 9, 9]).join(''));
```